# Adding a popup modal in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, activeadmin, simplemodal

I have a column on an active admin index page called domain. Each row in domain is a url. What I would like to do is add a modal that when clicked pops up an iframe of the url's website inside the modal window. I have looked at many resources without luck.Active admins customization seems somewhat restrictive to me. What would be the best way to approach this?

Thanks!